# How to know which QPushButton was pressed if they are created dynamically

Tags: qt

I am creating dynamic QPushButtons on a form and unfortunately the clicked signal does not take arguments (if it did I could have passed the name of button as a parameter) however since it does not I have no way of telling which pushButton was pressed. Currently All my pushbutton click events are connected to a single slot. Any suggestion on how I could find out which pushButton was pressed.

Comment: Check the [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html) class out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QObject::sender()` from your slot to get the pointer to `QPushButton` that sent the signal. Consider using `QButtonGroup` for this task if you want better code.